# Confusion about list_head children of linux kernel

Tags: linux, process, kernel

I want to traverse all the processes and try to show pid,ppid,first children  pid as well as the next sibling pid of each process. 
It seems that some children pids showed in my test result are incorrect.

[image]

For example,process 3,4,5,...,16,17,..are all children of process 2. But from the data it also shows that process 4,5,14,18..their first child refer to process 16!

My code attached here:

```
struct prinfo p;

p.state = t->state;     /* get state */
p.pid = t->pid;     /* get pid */
p.parent_pid = t->parent->pid; /* get parent pid */

struct list_head *chd;  /* get first child_task */
chd = &(t->children);
struct task_struct *child_task;
child_task = list_entry(chd->next, struct task_struct, sibling);
p.first_child_pid = child_task->pid; 

struct list_head *sbl; /* get next sibling_task */
sbl = &(t->sibling);
struct task_struct *sibling_task;
sibling_task = list_entry(sbl->next, struct task_struct, sibling);
p.next_sibling_pid = sibling_task->pid; 

p.uid = t->cred->uid;  /* get uid */
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You should check whether `childred` list is not empty (`list_empty(chd)`) before using it. Attempt to dereference elements of the empty list leads to *undefined behavior*, so it could show anything (or simply crach).

Comment: Yes I found it's exactly that problem! Thank you : )